# How to perform structure learning for Bayesian network given already partially constructed Bayesian network?

Tags: reference-request, algorithm-request, bayesian-inference, bayesian-networks

Let's assume that we have a dataset of variables (random events)I apriori would like to set dependency conditions between some of them and perform structure learning to figure out the rest of the Bayesian network.

How can this be done practically (e.g. some libraries, like [bnlearn](https://www.bnlearn.com/)) or, at least, in theory?

I was trying to google it, but haven't found anything related.

Answer (score 0):

The *hill climbing* or the *constraint-based structure learning* algorithms accept *whitelist* or *blacklist* arguments permitting or prohibitting some arcs.

Comment: This is an old question, but are you referring to the implementation of these algorithms from this library https://www.bnlearn.com/? Please, edit this answer to include these details.